# Почему нельзя создать экземпляр?

Tags: java

```
public class Entity<E> {
    public void Action() {

        // Вот тут возникает ошибка
        E entity = new E();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что заранее неизвестно с каким классом (Е) будет работать твой класс. Соответственно неизвестно есть ли у класса Е public конструкторы.

Answer (score 2):

[@Vadim](/users/1491/vadim) прав, но если вам очень хочется тогда можно сделать так:

```
abstract class Entity<E>
{
   public void Action ()
   {
      final E entity = createEntity ();
   }

   protected abstract E createEntity ();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

показал бы интерфейс класса E было бы понятнее
И кстати название E - плохое название для класса,оно не отображает его предназначение

Comment: вы, наверно, не заметили, что E - параметр типа

Comment: Не в этом суть. название класса должно отображать его смысл.
я бы его назвал Entity (судя из контекста
)